# In PHP how do I re-arrange the response data

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to re-arrange the response data with psql using PHP. So far I created this PHP script.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'pwd';
$db = 'prod_db';
$query = "select id, invoicenumber, customerid, orderstatusid, orderdiscount, salestax, salestax2, salestax3, orderamount, billingfirstname, billinglastname, billingcompany, billingaddress, billingaddress2, billingcity, billingstate, billingzipcode, billingcountry, billingphonenumber, billingemail, billingpaymentmethod, billingonlinepayment, billingpaymetmethodid, customercomments, internalcomments, externalcomments, cardtype, referer, ip, userid, lastupdate, affiliatecommision, transactionlist, orderitemlist, shipmentlist, questionlist from _3DCartOrders";

    $con = pg_connect ("dbname=$db user=$user");

    $result = pg_query($con, $query); 

    $aa = pg_fetch_all($result);

    print_r($aa); die();
```

And I got the results like this.

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 117521862
            [invoicenumber] => 62795
            [customerid] => 0
            [orderstatusid] => 4
            [orderdiscount] => 
            [salestax] => 
            [salestax2] => 
            [salestax3] => 
            [orderamount] => 232.16
            [billingfirstname] => David
            [billinglastname] => B
            [billingemail] => 
            [billingaddress] => 1408 PURDY AVE
            [billingaddress2] => 
            [billingcity] => Chandler
            [billingstate] => Arizona
            [billingzipcode] => 85224
            [billingcountry] => US
            [billingphone] => 6026808507
            [billingemail] => anand@jjbee.com
            [billingcompany] => 
            [customercomments] => Please send item as gift.  Do not put receipt outside the box.
            [internalcomments] => Do not put receipt outside the box.
            [externalcomments] => Do not put receipt outside the box.
            [transactionlist] => {"{\"OrderID\": 34, \"TransactionID\": \"543\", \"TransactionAVS\": \"\", \"TransactionCVV2\": \"\", \"TransactionType\": \"CA\", \"TransactionAmount\": 2.16, \"TransactionMethod\": \" CBA - New Order\", \"TransactionIndexID\": 562, \"TransactionApproval\": \"c56954\", \"TransactionCaptured\": 0, \"TransactionDateTime\": \"2015-05-20T18:36:56\", \"TransactionGatewayID\": 00, \"TransactionReference\": \"\", \"TransactionResponseCode\": \"\", \"TransactionResponseText\": \"\"}","{\"OrderID\": 284, \"TransactionID\": \"6150\", \"TransactionAVS\": \"\", \"TransactionCVV2\": \"\", \"TransactionType\": \"CA\", \"TransactionAmount\": 232.16, \"TransactionMethod\": \"Amazon CBA - Ready to Ship\", \"TransactionIndexID\": 57666, \"TransactionApproval\": \"a6846a\", \"TransactionCaptured\": 0, \"TransactionDateTime\": \"2015-05-20T18:51:42\", \"TransactionGatewayID\": 400, \"TransactionReference\": \"\", \"TransactionResponseCode\": \"\", \"TransactionResponseText\": \"\"}"}
            [discount] => 20.00

        )
```

Expected Output:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 117521862
            [invoicenumber] => 62795
            [customerid] => 0
            [orderstatusid] => 4
            [orderdiscount] => 
            [salestax] => 0.00
            [salestax2] => 0.00
            [salestax3] => 0.00
            [BillingAddress] => Array
                (
                    [FirstName] => Fiona
                    [LastName] => Mak
                    [Email] => fion@ddfail.com
                    [Address] => 28 Byng Ave
                    [Address2] => Unit 1509
                    [City] => Toronto
                    [ZipCode] => M2N 7H4
                    [StateCode] => ON
                    [CountryCode] => CA
                    [Phone] => 4168782690
                    [Company] => 

                )

            [Comments] => Array
                (
                    [OrderComment] => Please send item as gift.  Do not put receipt outside the box, put it inside the box
                    [OrderInternalComment] => Please send item as gift.  Do not put receipt outside the box.
                    [OrderExternalComment] => 11/15/2015 by Automated Script
                )

            [PaymentMethod] => Secure Online Payment
            [CardType] => Mastercard
            [Time] => 5:02:38 PM
            [Transaction] => Array
                (
                    [CVV2] => Pass
                    [ResponseText] => 
                    [AVS] => Street-Fail/Zip-Pass
                    [TransactionId] => PG056191
                    [ApprovalCode] => 071066
                    [TransactionType] => Sale
                    [Amount] => 206.61
                )

            [Discount] => 20.00
```

How can I group the Billing, Comments and Transaction items. Please share your valuable thoughts it would help to develop the script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want the result from database be like this? or you just want to rearrange after getting the result, the array?

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan, Thanks for your quick response! I would like to re-arrange the data after getting the results

Comment: @Anand better would be storing the billing data as a json object in database, that will make your work really simple.but if you want only to rearrange, you can a function using some regular expression to make this structure.What you have done with transaction is better example of what I would suggest you to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$billing["billingstuff"]=$aa["billingstuff"];
unset($aa["billingstuff"]);
//And so on with the billing stuff...

$aa["BillingAddress"] = $billing;
```

Same thing for comments.

And for transactionlist, since it is JSON encoded:

```
$transaction = json_decode($aa["transaction"], true));
$aa["Transaction"] = $transaction;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreation of the array, `json_decode` with the second param will cast it to array instead of object so you get your array.

```
$newAa = array();
foreach ( $aa as $columName => columnValue ) {
    if ( strstr( $columnName, 'billing' ) ) {
        $newAa[ 'BillingAddress' ][$columnName] = $columnValue;
    } elseif ( strstr( $columName, 'comments' ) ) {
        $newAa[ 'Comments' ][$columnName] = $columnValue;
    } elseif ( strstr( $columName, 'transactionlist' ) ) {
        $newAa[ 'Transaction' ] = json_decode( $columnValue, true );
    } else {
        $newAa[ $columName ] = $columnValue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourarray as $key => $element){
        if($key == 'FirstName' || $key == 'LastName' || $key == 'Email' || $key == 'Address' || $key == 'Address2' || $key == 'City' || $key == 'ZipCode' || $key == 'StateCode' || $key == 'CountryCode' || $key == 'Phone' || $key == 'Company'){
            $result['BillingAddress'][$key] = $element;
        } else if($key == 'OrderComment' || $key == 'OrderInternalComment' || $key == 'OrderExternalComment' ){
            $result['Comments'][$key] = $element;
        } else if ($key == 'CVV2' || $key == 'ResponseText' || $key == 'AVS' || $key == 'TransactionId' || $key == 'ApprovalCode' || $key == 'TransactionType' || $key == 'Amount'){
            $result['Transaction'][$key] = $element;
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $element;
        }
}
```